# Injecting JOOQ configuration using Guice

Tags: guice, jooq

We use Jooq extensively in our Dropwizard project, wanted to know if there is a way to Inject the Configuration into our service classes using Guice.

Updates to the Guice setup

```
public class SystemModule extends AbstractModule {

private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(SystemModule.class);
private static DataSource DATA_SOURCE;

static {
    try {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mariadb://" + System.getenv("DB_HOST") + ":" + System.getenv("DB_PORT") + "/sminq");
        config.setUsername(System.getenv("DB_USER"));
        config.setPassword(System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        config.setAutoCommit(false);
        DATA_SOURCE = new HikariDataSource(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.info("Datasource exception"+ ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Configuration providesFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
            .set(new SpringConnectionProvider(DATA_SOURCE))
            .set(SQLDialect.MARIADB)
            .set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new DatabaseLoggerService(DATA_SOURCE)));
    return configuration;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public DataSourceTransactionManager provideDataSourceTransactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(DATA_SOURCE));
}

@Provides
@Singleton
private DataSource provideDataSource() {
    return FiberDataSource.wrap(DATA_SOURCE);
}

@Override
protected void configure() {

    TransactionalMethodInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionalMethodInterceptor();
    requestInjection(interceptor);
    bindInterceptor(annotatedWith(Transactional.class), any(), interceptor);
    bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(Transactional.class), interceptor);

}
```

This is my Guice module where i setup the JOOQ and Spring configuration. The rest of the classes are exactly the same as in the example

Comment: Yes there is. An example of using jOOQ with Guice (and Spring) can be seen here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-guice-example. Do yuo have any specific issues?

Comment: I managed to get it to work with one of the dropwizard-jooq bundles.

Comment: OK, great! You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow. That might be very helpful to anyone else in the future, who finds this question via Google.

Comment: @LukasEder i was exploring your example, i am currently stuck with an issue my tests run only if BoneCP result.setDefaultAutoCommit(true); is set to true, when false all the transactions fail. I have followed the same example above.

Comment: Can you provide more information please? Ideally, a small example project showing how to reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: @LukasEder after some debugging the issue was on my side, i used the Transactional annotation on my interfaces which does not work, it has to be added to the implementation class.

Comment: @LukasEder does the Transactional annotation enforce start transaction/commit on every update/insert query. I am running some tests with the select for update queries and its not working as expected.

Comment: Hard to say... I hardly have any information at all about how you tried to set this up. Please, can you edit your question with much more information? As it is now, I cannot answer it, I'm afraid

Comment: Question update @LukasEder the module setup, picked up from your example.

Comment: @LukasEder ooh so is that a solution? or currently this wont work.

Comment: Then what does this example do? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-guice-example as the @Transactional annotations is used there

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about that third party contribution. Indeed, that example project still works (i.e. its tests run). But I guess it will still be easier if you produce a minimal reproducible test case somewhere. With these magic DI frameworks, very subtle mistakes might lead to stuff not working, and it's really hard to debug from just little information